# Google Script Libraries

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I was wondering if someone could help with some copy and paste coding I've been trying.

I have a master sheet (call it sheet a) where I store price and inventory information for all our products in USD, GBP and EUR.

I have a script that will update each store/site individually from a sheet - it's very long and completely over my head so beyond simple amends I can't do much to it. It means though that I have 3 other sheets (one per store) with the script attached to do updates.

It works great whereby once the data is in each sheet and I have another script that copies the relevant data into the relevant sheet at the click of a button.

However, I cannot seem to trigger the scripts in those sheets to run from Sheet A. I have deployed the scripts as libraries and tried calling them from the menu, but with no joy. My menu looks like this with the idea being that I call the function to update the store in the relevant sheet.

```
    function onOpen(e) {
    var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Update Shopify');
    menu.addItem('Update Stores', 'ShopifyUSInventory.updateStore');
    menu.addToUi();

     }
```

If I run the function from the library, it works perfectly, but I cannot make it work when clicking the button in the menu from Sheet A. 
I feel like I'm missing something obvious so it would be great to get some help and advice if poss.

Thanks
Ed

Comment: Is your function actually named "ShopifyUSInventory.updateStore"?

Comment: How do you declared the function that you are trying to call?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Hi guys, my library is shopifyusinventory and the function within that is updateStore. Ruben - I don't actually get any errors, when I press the button in script a it says the script is running and then finishes without any errors.. But when I look in the other sheets nothing had happened. Thanks in advance